# Exception in thread "main"

Tags: java, массивы, исключения, intellij-idea, многопоточность

Зеленый новичок.
Пытаюсь сделать простенькую библиотеку, но столкнулся с exception.

```
public class Main {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
    Launcher launchy = new Launcher();
    launchy.launch();
}
```

}

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Bookshelf extends ParametrClass {
   Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
   String[] bookShelfy = new String[bookShelfSize];
    public  void bookAdder() {
        System.out.println("Какое количество книг вы хотите добавить в список?(Введите цифру)");
           bookShelfSize = scan.nextInt();
             for (currentBookNumber = 1; currentBookNumber < bookShelfSize; currentBookNumber++) {
           System.out.println("Пожалуйста введите название книги " + currentBookNumber);
             bookShelfy[bookShelfSize] = scan.nextLine();
        }
    }
        public void bookShower() {
            System.out.println(bookShelfy);
}
```

}

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Какое значение bookShelfSize здесь

```
String[] bookShelfy = new String[bookShelfSize];
```

И какое значение у bookShelfSize ниже по коду здесь:

```
bookShelfy[bookShelfSize] = scan.nextLine();
```

В вашем случае создали массив на 5 элементов к примеру, а пытаетесь записать что-то в 6й элемент, который не существует. Исключение об этом вам и говорит, вы вышли за границы массива.

Comment: Благодарю, Cooler.